# How to change window CE desktop display and version number

Tags: windows-ce

I have some text showing on my WinCE desktop:

"Windows embedded CE v.6.00 (Build 3000 on Jan, 30, 2014)".  How can I change the build number?  I did the new build for several times now,  I would like to change "Build 3000" to a higher number.

Thank you,
Liang

Comment: Hi @Liang , Whether your WinCE installation is evaluation mode? because, i'm working with WinCE (WinCE7) and I'm not seeing any such text..

Comment: do you have any kind background image on the desktop?

Comment: @Liang , Yes. It has background image of default Windows CE .. Whether you want to change this image??

Comment: I do not know about winCE7, but I can see the build number if I set the background display image to none.  Anyway, that build number can be changed, it is assigned by Microsoft.  It can only be done manually,  please check \...\PUBLIC\SHELL\OAK\HPC\CESHELL\UI\desktopview.cpp

Comment: good to know that your problem is fixed :)

Comment: Please post it as an answer. It would save the time taken for reading through the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows embedded CE v.6.00 (Build 3000 on Jan, 30, 2014)", that build number 3000 can not be changed,  it is assigned by Microsoft. It can only be done manually, please check ...\PUBLIC\SHELL\OAK\HPC\CESHELL\UI\desktopview.cpp